# Encrypted form of letters from w to ~ is stored as ? in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I am encrypting the password and storing the encrypted password in the database. The Key for encryption is 8. For example, if my password is `abc`, then the encrypted form of abc will be `ijk` which is stored in the database. Till the letter `v`, this is working properly. The ASCII value of `v` is 118. So, 118+8=126 i.e; `~` will be stored as the encrypted form of v. But, from the letter `w` till the `~` i.e; from 119 to 126, the encrypted form of these letters stored in database is `?`. Is there any better way to encrypt these 8 letters?

Comment: That's not encryption. At least, not the sort that decent people use. It's so weak, you may as well not use it. If you want to use encryption, then use an actual, well built implementation of something that's strong.

Comment: In your database table, change password field data type to nvarchar or ntext to support those charcters.

Comment: "Is there any better way?" The question should be "Is there any worse way?"

Comment: @podiluska well, it could be ROT13. For added security, I always apply ROT13 **twice**.

Answer (score 6):

> I am encrypting the password and storing the encrypted password in the database.

Also known as "doing it wrong". You do not encrypt and store passwords. You should *cryptographically hash* them (with salt).

> The Key for encryption is 8. For example, if my password is `abc`, then the encrypted form of abc will be `ijk` which is stored in the database.

That is not encryption; it is *barely* obfuscation.

> Is there any better way to encrypt these 8 letters?

If you want to store non-text characters, either use a `varbinary(...)` or use base-64 to store arbitrary binary as string data (the first is more efficient).

However, it must be emphasized that your current process is very very wrong, and you shouldn't be doing that. I'm reluctant to help you make such a fundamental security mistake.

The correct thing to do here is to use a well-known, reliable secure hashing function (with salt), and hash the password, storing only the hash. To test a password, you run the same hashing algorithm (and same salt) against what the user enters, and *compare the hashes*. You should **not**, even with god access and knowledge of all the magic numbers, be able to decrypt password data to recover the actual password.